# loading input dataset for every iteration in for loop in palantir

Tags: pandas, pyspark, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I have a @transform_pandas code which loads the input file for computing.

Inside the compute function I have a for loop which has to read the complete input data and filter accordingly for every iteration.

```
    @transform_pandas(
    Output("/FCA_Foundry/dataset1"),
    source_df=Input(sample),
    )
```

I have the below code where I'm trying to read source_df dataset for every iteration in for loop and filter the dataset specifically to the year and family and do the computation.

```
    def compute(source_df):
        for entire_row in vhcl_df.itertuples():
            modyr = entire_row[1]
            fam = str(entire_row[2])
    
            /* source_df should be read again here.

            source_df = source_df.loc[source_df['i_yr']==modyr]
            source_df = source_df.loc[source_df['fam']==fam]
            ...
```

Is there a way to achieve this. Thank you for your support.

Comment: I don't know pandas, but if you are overriding the `source_df`  variable with data that came from a filter, next time the loop iterates you'll be trying to filter data that has already been filtered with. Looks like an implementation bug

Comment: hello thank you for your reply. can you elaborate more on what is implementation bug? I'm new to palantir.

Comment: Why don't you create a copy of source_df in the first line of the transform?

Comment: hi nicornk, the source_df needs to be read again in the for loop for next iteration. The source_df has to be reset with full data in the loop. can you help to understand if this is possible making a copy in the transform code?

Comment: This is not really a foundry question, but have you tried https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html ?

Answer (score 2):

As already suggested by @nicornk in the comments, you should create a new `.copy()` item of your `source_df` right after you declare the transform.

The two filtering steps (that can ben also merged in one, if you don't need to work just on the "modyr filtered" source_df.

Please note that `modyr`, `fam` are actual colnames of `vhcl_df`, it is actually sufficient to

```
@transform_pandas(
    Output("/FCA_Foundry/dataset1"),
    source_df=Input(sample),
    vhcl_df=Input(path)
)
def compute(source_df, vhcl_df):
    for modyr, fam in vhcl_df.items():
        temp_df = source_df.copy()
        temp_df = source_df.loc[source_df['i_yr']==modyr]
        temp_df = source_df.loc[source_df['fam']==str(fam)]
```

which, in a more concise and clean way is actually writable as

```
def compute(source_df, vhcl_df):
    for modyr, fam in vhcl_df.items():
        temp_df = source_df.copy()
        filtered_temp_df = temp_df[(temp_df.i_yr==modyr) & (temp_df.fam==str(fam))]
```

PS: Remember that if `source_df` is big, [you should proceed with PySpark (see foundry docs)](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/transforms-python-api/#transform_pandas)

> Note that `transform_pandas` should only be used on datasets that can fit into memory. If you have larger datasets that you wish to filter down first before converting to Pandas, you should write your transformation using the `transform_df()` decorator and the `pyspark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame()` method.